# dc.js sort datatable by multiple columns

Tags: dc.js

I have used dc.js to create data table and my requirement is to sort the data table by descending order of multiple columns. I have used following code:

```
.order(d3.descending)
     .sortBy(function (d) {
           return d.columnOne;
           return d.columnTwo;
});
```

Please help.

Comment: What you have there will just return `d.columnOne` and ignore the rest. Are you trying to use `d.columnTwo` as a secondary sorting key?

Comment: Yeah Gordon, I want to sort multiple columns of data table, column properties are `d.columnOne` and `d.columnTwo`.

Answer (score 2):

Your function that you pass to `sortBy` needs to return a single key that will lexicographically or numerically sort the rows in the order that you want.

It is not possible to return two values as you are attempting to do there. Instead,

1. if both columns are strings join the values as strings, separated by a character that has a lower ASCII value than any character in `columnOne`, or
2. if both columns are numeric, multiply `columnOne` by a number which is greater than any value in `columnTwo` and then add the two
   values

Approach one, for strings:

```
.order(d3.descending)
     .sortBy(function (d) {
           return [d.columnOne,d.columnTwo].join('\x0');
});
```

Approach two, for numbers

```
.order(d3.descending)
     .sortBy(function (d) {
           return d.columnOne * 1e9 + d.columnTwo;
});
```

I apologize in advance if there are any errors in this code, as it is untested.

I don't know of any way to do this if one column is numeric and the other is a string.

Answer (score 1):

Gordon's method worked for me, with a minor adjustment

My two columns were one string, one numeric and I used

```
.sortBy(function (d) {
    return [d.columnOne,d.columnTwo].join();
});
```

That did the trick. Thanks Gordon! :-)

Comment: Glad I could help. However, watch out that you're not getting lexicographical sorting rather than numeric sorting on the numbers. E.g. "A,10" will sort lower than "A,2" as a string. The only way I can think to work around this is to make sure your numbers are zero-padded to the maximum width, e.g. "A,10", "A,02".

Comment: For that matter, "10,A" will sort lower than "2,A" as a string.

Comment: A belated thanks. You were spot on. I realised late into the night that was what had happened and also that padding the 0s would enforce it correctly. Thanks again.